# Cannot install Deepin 15.8 on SSD

Tags: linux, debian, deepin

I tried to install Deepin 15.8 on my 120GB WD SSD but after installation, every time I try to boot it, it gives me this:

```
error: attempt to read or write outside of disk hd0
error: please load kernel first
```

Then, installed Deepin on my HDD and it works perfectly well. I tried to erase the SSD using this guide: https://grok.lsu.edu/Article.aspx?articleid=16716
Even after erasing the drive, I cannot install Deepin on it. What can be the problem?